# Any whiteboard animation software for Ubuntu or Linux?

Tags: software-installation, graphics, animations

Is there any standalone easy-to-use whiteboard animation software like EasySketch Pro 2, Explaindio or VideomakerFX for Ubuntu or Linux in general?

To TIM: Please do NOT edit without understanding. Ubuntu, Linux, EasySketch Pro, Explaindio and VidomakerFX all are proper nouns and should be started with capital letters. And FLOSS means Free and Libre Open Source Softwares, fyi.

Comment: Like these http://labs.opinsys.com/blog/2011/04/13/installing-interactive-whiteboard-software-on-ubuntu/ ?

Comment: Nope, I am referring to "whiteboard animation software", not whiteboard software per se. Please have a look at the whiteboard animation presentation at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgE_2SNZziY for a reference. Anyway, thanks Rinzwind for replying.

Comment: So just some animation software? There isn't much for linux. Have a look on alternativeto.net and see if anything comes up for the Adobe After Effects search.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Sparkol VideoScribe in Wine on Ubuntu 13 in the past. VideoScribe is a great tool, but I'm not sure if it will still work with Wine.

http://alternativeto.net/software/videoscribe/ does not offer a whole lot of alternatives that are Linux friendly

Comment: VideoScribe is a great tool, so is After Effects whiteboard animation kits, but they are not FLOSS.  I support FLOSSOne can create whiteboard animation manually in either Cinelerra, KDEnlive or Blender, but would be very time consuming. That is the reason I am searching for an alternative, fyi. Anyway thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No problem. Let's hope as Desktop Linux grows, more software will  be native Linux. In the mean time, I'm dual booting or using Wine :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) or [Krita](https://krita.org) + [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) + [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).  Here's how:

- Open a new blank Inkscape document.
- Go to File -> Document Properties and set the Background to black.
- Zoom to Page Width.
- Select a drawing tool.  Brush strokes work well.
- Start a screen capture in OBS and return to Inkscape.
- Record your video.
- [Crop the video using FFMpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/510985/how-can-i-crop-a-video-to-a-part-of-the-view).

Really any drawing program should work.  You probably need a [pen input device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TB0TTAC) to make this look good, regardless of the software you use.

Answer (score 0):

Video Scribe works well on Ubuntu 16. Installed using playonlinux. Works like a charm

Comment: Duplicate of [existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/586586/344926)